# PHP & JSON: Inserting an array in a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am creating a JSON structure to be passed back to Ajax. I would like to insert `'para' => "Hello"` into `"content"` like this:

```
{
    "sections": {
        "content": [{
            "para": "Hello"
        }]
    }
}
```

I tried using this code:

```
$array = array('sections' => array());
array_push($array["sections"], array("content" => array())); // content must be initialized as empty
array_push($array["sections"][0], array("para" => "Hello"));
```

But I received this instead:

```
{
    "sections": [{
        "content": [],
        "0": {
            "para": "Hello"
        }
    }]
}
```

If I try `array_push($array["sections"]["content"], array("para" => "Hello"))`, I get an error instead. How do I insert an array into `"content"`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: tip: create the content array first. then insert it into the general structure to json encode. done that way will allow you to validate with `var_dump` the array actually contains what you expect. also double-check you're using the right options when calling [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode).

Comment: @hakre The problem is that I am using a `for` loop to process one big chunk of data before I can send anything to `json_encode`. Thus, I need a direct way to insert objects/arrays into `content`. It is easy to insert a second dimension of arrays for `sections` by writing `array_push($array['sections'], array('content' => array()))` but I have no idea how to use `array_push` for the next array dimension.

Comment: `array_push(...)` is equal to `$array[] = $valueToBePushed;`. Both do not handle array *dimensions* because an array first of all is *flat*, so there is only one dimension. however, nothing stops you to create an *array inside an array* which is also known as multi-dimensional array. That's why I suggested to build the content array first. This will simplify what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your intentions correctly, here's the array structure you're aiming for:

```
array("sections" => array(
    "content" => array("para" => "Hello"),
));
```

However, in Javascript [] represents an array and {} represents an object. If you're trying to create an object with a property of "0", that's not possible in PHP. [Variable names](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) have to start with a letter or underscore.

Here's an array of `content` objects:

```
$content = new stdClass();
$content->para = 'hello';

array("sections" => array(
    "content" => array($content),
));
```

To add arrays of contents:

```
array("sections" => array(
    "content" => array(
        array("para" => "Hello"),
        array("para" => "Hello"),
        array("para" => "Hello"),
    ),
));
```

You can also construct your own contents array first if you're iterating over an index and then json_encode it. Basic example:

```
$content = array();

for (i=0; i <3; i++) {
    $content[] = array('para' => 'hello');
}

json_encode(array("sections" => array(
    "content" => array($content),
)));
```

To convert that to JSON, put your array inside a `json_encode()` call.

Comment: `"content" => array(array("para" => "Hello), array("para" => "World"))` is the structure I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array['sections'] = array("content" => array(array("para" => "Hello")));
echo json_encode($array);
```

will give the result in desired format

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I want to do something like this: `$array['sections'] = array('content' => array());` and expand from there, what should I do?

Comment: You mean how do you keep adding to your `content` array? Added several more examples.